# How to show that a map is $K$-multilinear

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, multilinear-algebra

Hey I have this exercise where I have some questions

For a field $K$, let $x =\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}, y = \begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\\y_3\end{pmatrix}, z = \begin{pmatrix}z_1\\z_2\\z_3\end{pmatrix} $be elements in $K^3$.

Which of the following mappings $µ: K^3 × K^3 × K^3 → K$ are $K$-multilinear, which are $K$-multilinear and alternating?

(a) $µ(x, y, z) := y_2$

(b) $µ(x, y, z) := x_1y_2z_3 − x_1x_2y_3$

(c) $µ(x, y, z) := x_3y_1z_2$

(d) $µ(x, y, z) := x_1y_2z_3 + x_3y_1z_2 + x_2y_3z_1 − x_3y_2z_1 − x_2y_1z_3 − x_1y_3z_2$

So I know that "a multilinear map is a function of several variables that is linear separately in each variable".

So what I need now to prove for every exercise is that

$µ(x+\alpha j, y, z)=µ(x, y, z)+\alphaµ( j, y, z)$

$µ(x, y+\alpha j, z)=µ(x, y, z)+\alphaµ( x, j, z)$

$µ(x, y, z+\alpha j)=µ(x, y, z)+\alphaµ( x, y, j)$, right?

As you can see it can be take a lot of time to do all these steps.

My question is: is there a faster method to show that a map is multilinear? (for example using matrices)

Comment: You may be able to use symmetry arguments in some cases to reduce the computations

Comment: Okay, but only in this way could I speed everything up? @MPW

Comment: By "a space $K$" you probably mean "a field $K$".

Comment: Yes , I have edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu:(K^n)^m\to K$ is $m$-linear iff $\mu(v_1,\dots,v_m)$ ($v_i\in K^n$) is a linear combination of monomials of the form
$$v_{1,i_1}\dots v_{m,i_m}$$
i.e. monomials where each of the $m$ vectors contributes exactly once in the product, by one of its coordinates.

E.g. in your exercise, it is $3$-linear in cases c, d but not in cases a, b (in b, $x$ contributes twice).